# How does the Rangers Spirit effect recharge time work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, Rangers have Spirit skills in which a spirit is summoned and while the spirit is alive, it gives an effect to nearby allies. One such spirit is called [Sun Spirit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sun_Spirit) and its description (directly copied from the in-game description) is:

```
Summon a sun spirit that grants allies a chance to inflict burning.
Sun Spirit (6s): 35% chance to apply burning on hit.
Burning: 3 s (984 damage)
Effect recharge: 10 seconds
Duration: 60 s
```

Is the effect recharge (10 seconds) shared so that if one ally procs the burning, then no one can proc the burning for 10 seconds?

Or each affected ally have their own effect recharge timer.

Additionally what does the (6s) after Sun Spirit mean?

Comment: My guess is that it can only apply the affect - chance to cause burning - to each ally once every 6 seconds. So you'll get a 35% chance to cause burning for 3s, every 6 seconds. Overall, that gives you 10 chances to cause burning.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Ignore completely what I wrote previously - I was going by how I normally read effect descriptions and by what I remembered from using it in WvW a long while ago, but in this case it seems to work completely differently from I would have expected. I'm not sure whether the description on this skill's tooltip is incorrect (wouldn't be the first time that happened) or whether my initial interpretation of it was just way off.

Simple enough to try out, and I finally took the time to do so. The effect lasts for 6 seconds each time it's applied, but, strangely, it seems to be re-applied every 3 seconds, starting about 3 seconds after the spirit is created. It almost seems as though the "skill" of the sun spirit has a 3 second cast time, and it keeps casting it. Hovering over its affect description while in the vicinity of a sun spirit, you can see that it keeps cycling "5s... 4s... 3s... 5s... 4s... 3s..." (i.e. 5.99s -> 3.0s countdown) until the spirit dies, then (again no idea why this is the case) about 3s *after* the spirit dies, you get the final 6s (5s, 4s, 3s, 2s, 1s, 0s, gone) of the effect.

While affected by the spirit's boon, I was able to inflict burning on my targets within very few hits; switching targets right after applying burning, I'm relatively certain I was able to inflict burning again within less than 10 seconds, but I could be wrong on that one. I also haven't had time to confirm with others whether the cooldown is shared, but will attempt to do so later this week (when my workload allows).

If anyone can confirm or expand on this, it would help to let me know I'm not going crazy, as the way this works is very counterintuitive from what I've come to expect about how to read skill descriptions.

Comment: So the buff given by the spirit lasts 6 seconds, and you get the buff every 10 seconds for a minute. Sounds legit.

Comment: I dont think this is correct. While I was within range of the sun spirit. I had the sun spirit effect permanently. It kept cycling 6 seconds. So the effect renewed at the end of the first 6 seconds and it kept repeating until the spirit died.

Comment: @Jay: You're absolutely right - I've completely re-written my answer based on a recent test. It's not renewed _at the end of the first 6 seconds_, but every 3 seconds.